# How to start an Xfce plugin?

Tags: xfce, plugin

After having built and installed a Xfce4 plugin. How do I start it?
I have located these files:

```
/usr/local/lib/xfce4/panel/plugins/libsystemload.so
/usr/local/share/xfce4/panel/plugins/systemload.desktop
```

Answer (score -1):

The plugins are installed in:

```
/usr/share/xfce4/panel/plugins/
/usr/lib64/xfce4/panel/plugins/
```

By running `sudo /usr/bin/xfce4-settings-manager`, going to the Items tab, one can add plugins which are then looked for in the above mentioned paths.

My issue was that the plugin was not installed on the correct path.

Comment: The actual issue is that XFCE4 is *dumb* and supports only one plugin location (very bad style for a piece of Linux software… but then, lots of rather young folks these days that don't even remember /usr/local)